# a problem in real analysis & measure theory

Tags: real-analysis

suppose we have  $A\subset\mathbb{R}^2$  and the 1 dimensional measure of the intersection of A and every vertical line is zero.is it true that the 2 dimensional measure of A is zero?

what is the answer if we asumme A is compact?

pls answer with the least use of measure theory. 
thnx

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable. Let $\mu_x$, $\mu_y$ denote the Lebesgue measure on the $x$ and $y$-axis. By Fubini theorem, we have
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_A(x,y) d\mu_y\right) d\mu_x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\chi_A(x,y) d(\mu_x\times\mu_y) = \mu_x\times\mu_y(A),$$
where $\mu_x\times\mu_y$ is the Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb{R}^2$. By our assumption, the function (of x) $\int_\mathbb{R} \chi_A(x,y) d\mu_y = \mu_y(\{y\in \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \in A \})= 0$ for each fixed $x$.

Comment: what if A is compact?is it again 0?

Comment: Yes, the result holds for all measurable sets, which include compact sets.

Comment: The notations $\mu_x$ and $\mu_y$ are awful. Please replace them both by $\mu$.